# Rails Generate Model with out Migration Files

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created the data modeling and imported the sql file and generated the schema for all my models as below. Now i want to generate the models for all my tables in the MySQl with out the migration files.

Also i have two namescopes and want to use the same model for all the controllers with different namescope.

```
# Create a new Rails Project
rails new <project-name> -d mysql

# Run Bundler
bundle install

# Database Initiation
rake db:create

# Dump SQL file into MySQL
mysql -u hmv -p <database-name> < <database-file>

# Generate SQL Schema from the MySQL tables
rake db:schema:dump

# Creating a Git Repo for Versioning and Collaboration
git init
git remote add origin https://<Username>:<Password>@bitbucket.org/harshamv/<Project-Name>.git
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
git push -u origin master

# Create the Initial Migration File
rails generate migration initial_schema_dump

# Copy the Content from the Schema file to the migration file and run the following command
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `--skip_migration` option

```
rails g model MyModel --skip_migration
  invoke      active_record
  create      app/models/my_model.rb
  invoke      test_unit
  create      test/models/my_model_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/my_models.yml
```

Comment: is there a way to Mass generate this from all the tables from the Schema?

Comment: Not that Im aware of. Will comment here if I come across anything.

Comment: thanks alot. some expectations when you move from other frameworks :P